# RequireJS baseURL issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

If i load at my domain.com/seeker/job page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('assets/backbone/js/libs/require/require.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('assets/backbone/main.js')}}"></script>
```

main.js file

```
 require.config({
 baseUrl: "/",
       paths:{
           "jquery": "domain.com/js/libs/jquery/src/jquery",
           "underscore": "domain.com/js/libs/underscore/underscore",
           "backbone": "domain.com/js/libs/backbone/backbone"
       },
        waitSeconds: 7
    });

   require(['assets/backbone/app'], function(AppView){
    new AppView;
});
```

Error

```
GET http://domain.com/manipulation/_evalUrl.js 500 (Internal Server Error) require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: manipulation/_evalUrl
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET http://domain.com/ajax.js 500 (Internal Server Error) require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: ajax
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET http://domain.com/serialize.js 500 (Internal Server Error) require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: serialize
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET http://domain.com/ajax/jsonp.js 500 (Internal Server Error) require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: ajax/jsonp
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET http://domain.com/ajax/xhr.js 500 (Internal Server Error) require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: ajax/xhr
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET http://domain.com/ajax/script.js 500 (Internal Server Error) require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: ajax/script
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET http://domain.com/ajax/load.js 500 (Internal Server Error) require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: ajax/load
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET http://domain.com/effects.js 500 (Internal Server Error) require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: effects
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET http://domain.com/effects/animatedSelector.js 500 (Internal Server Error) require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: effects/animatedSelector
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET http://domain.com/dimensions.js 500 (Internal Server Error) require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: dimensions
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET http://domain.com/exports/amd.js 500 (Internal Server Error) require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: exports/amd
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET http://domain.com/deprecated.js 500 (Internal Server Error) require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: deprecated
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET http://domain.com/offset.js 500 (Internal Server Error) require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: offset
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: 
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
```

The error list is much long, it acted as if it cant find the URL and it's loading off the base url? What did i do wrong?

Comment: Are you able to load http://domain.com/seeker/templates/views/app.js in your browser? A 500 Error usually means that there is a problem serving this file to you.

Comment: i cant because of the word Seeker and that's not even the url it should be in, it should be domain.com/assets/backbone/js/libs/<anyLib>

Comment: Can you provide the full URLs for the files you need? require.js, main.js, app.js, jquery.js, etc.

Comment: @Alphadelta14 I did try that, but the fact is no matter what i do to the paths now , i will still have the above error first.

Comment: I meant in your question. It would help me answer your question if your question had slightly better details.

Comment: @Alphadelta14 As in the Real URL? Sry i'm brain dead, been trying to fix this for too long

Comment: Like http://domain.com/js/libs/jquery/src/jquery.js
You can leave the domain anonymized. The structure is what counts.

Comment: @Alphadelta14 I updated :) The URL should be right, when i make a type it says cant be found but when i put the correct url, it error 500 so many files!

Comment: Closer. This time, with the actual intended URLs. If you are tired of listing them, just do at least the 4 I requested before: require.js, main.js, app.js, jquery.js

Comment: @Alphadelta14 Sry, i didnt catch you on that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to have `/templates` as the first part of the URL, try setting the baseUrl. By default it is `./` which resolves to your `/seeker` directory.

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/",
    paths:{
        "jquery": "js/libs/jquery/src/jquery",
        "underscore": "js/libs/underscore/underscore",
        "backbone": "js/libs/backbone/backbone"
    },
    waitSeconds: 7
});
```

Comment: It's too complicated, when i fix a , b appears, when i fix b, a appears. I'm stuck with this code for days, Would be great if you could teamview me :(

Comment: Sorry if I'm hijacking this thread, but I wanted to ask a related follow-up question to Alphadelta14. Do you know if baseUrl is supposed to be relative to the script in which it's defined or relative to the file that included that script as its data-main? I include my main.js via an absolute path. My baseUrl is then something like "core" meaning I want it to be a subdirectory "core" of the directory in which main.js resides. Instead it sets it as a subdirectory "core" of the directory in which the referring HTML file resides. It only works if I set baseUrl to be an absolute path.

Comment: baseUrl is relative to the HTML, or it can be absolute. For that reason, it is generally preferred to be absolute.

Answer (score 0):

saw this one year post and I have the same exact issue.

The file of jquery you are trying to extract is not from "src" folder, but "dist".

So, in your main.js file, change a line to

```
"jquery": "domain.com/js/libs/jquery/dist/jquery"
```